# how to set printer preferences common to all domain users

Tags: windows-xp, active-directory, printer, preferences

I have a client with windows xp professional. This client has a printer phisically connected. There are a lot of users who login to this computer using domain authentication.
Unluckily the first time each user logins I have to set printer preferences (paper size, margins and so on) for each one. Since there are about fifty users is there any way to set the same printer preferences for all these users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are actually logging in to that computer, and not just connecting to it, I would log in as a new user, set the profile with all settings I wanted, and then copy that profile to the default profile.

Then any new users logging in would get that default profile with all the printer settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to modify the printing defaults for the system?
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305402